# PHP Cache XML file then read data from it

Tags: php, xml, curl, caching

So, I have this function to read a specific xml file from curl and its working fine, although Im trying to implement a function to store/cache the file and then read the file.
Also, I need to add a little extra while saving the file,
I need to write the current timestamp, so when I call the function,
IF the timestamp from cached XML file is above 1hour from the current timestamp, it loads the curl again and writes the new data on the local XML file,
ELSE loads the data from cached XML.

**EDIT:** I can use the function filemtime() to get the last modified dated of the file, instead of write the current timestamp in the cached file on every request, mentioned by @CBroe

Answer in the comments. Thanks @CBroe

Comment: Why would you need to store the timestamp anywhere separately; your file system should already be able to give you the last modified timestamp of the XML file you got stored.

Comment: good point, never thought about it. I ve learned to do this way it works but i will have a look into that. Cheers

Comment: @CBroe filemtime() found it! I'll try this method later, seems a way easier!

Comment: You can either make our cURL request the way you currently do - then you should use `file_put_contents` to write `$xml` to your local file (which will update its modified time as well), and then keep working with `simplexml_load_string($xml);` - or use the `CURLOPT_FILE` to make cURL write the received response to the file directly, and then use `simplexml_load_file` instead.

Comment: @Cbroe Bingo! you're the man! working like a charm. I just need to set the if statement with filemtime(), i should be able to do that easy